# Nested query to find child containing term X and child's parent contains term Y

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a mapping like this

```
{
    "properties" : {
        "text" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties": {
                "header": {
                    "type" : "text"
                },
                "nodes": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "subheader" : {
                            "type" : "text"
                        },
                        "nodes" : {
                            "type" : "nested"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'll like to return the documents where  the innermost child `text.nodes.nodes` contains some term 'X' if and only if that child's parent `text.nodes.subheader` contains some term 'Y'

Here's a [reproducible gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/74be1e1f1bbb25ba1e27d37c258f9942), where I expect that a search for 'SUPERFRAGILISTIC' in the child, and 'Restrictions' in the subheader should return only document 2.
It is now returning both documents.

From the gist, my query right now looks like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "text.nodes",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "text.nodes.subheader": {
                        "query": "Restrictions"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "text.nodes.nodes",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "text.nodes.nodes.content": {
                        "query": "SUPERFRAGILISTIC"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find a result with two conditions that are contained in the same json node of a single document, you need to nest the second condition in the first one. With this query you'll get only document2:

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "nested":{
                  "path":"text.nodes",
                  "query":{
                     "bool":{
                        "must":[
                           {
                              "match":{
                                 "text.nodes.subheader":{
                                    "query":"Restrictions"
                                 }
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "nested":{
                                 "path":"text.nodes.nodes",
                                 "query":{
                                    "bool":{
                                       "must":[
                                          {
                                             "match":{
                                                "text.nodes.nodes.content":{
                                                   "query":"SUPERFRAGILISTIC"
                                                }
                                             }
                                          }
                                       ]
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```